# How to crop the background from an inclined image?

Tags: python, image-processing

The input is an image(document) from the scanner and my task is to crop the background and return only the document, just like this: [Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdgtZ.jpg) [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBqXS.jpg)

I've done this through thresholding and getbbox:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as pli
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu as otsu
from PIL import Image

cnh_gray = Image.open("cnh.jpg").convert('L')
cnh_gray.save('cnhgray.jpg')

img = pli.imread('cnhgray.jpg')
imagem = Image.open('cnhgray.jpg')

thresh = otsu(img)
mask = img < thresh

msk = Image.fromarray(mask,'L')

box = msk.getbbox()

crop = imagem.crop(box)
```

The problem is: The getbbox function doesn't work when the document isn't vertical. Since I don't know the angle, how can I rotate the image to use the getbbox funcion? If there's another function that I can use for inclined images instead of getbbox, please tell me.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have to do this for just this image? or 1000s?  If the latter, are all doc of the same form or not?  I believe rotation loses resolution, but if required, you need landmarks.  For the doc shown, upper left, upper right, and lower right solid black corners should do.  For 1 doc, select by eye with magnifier.  For many, you need to write a program to find them for particular doc.  If rotation can be skipped, just removed nearly all white lines and columns from edges inward.  Doing this first might help landmark search.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I have to do this for lots of images. I was able to find the angle using Hough transform and right now I'm trying to remove the black background which came with the rotation plus the original white background.